# Apply a function if column name is in a list in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

Okay, I am probably pursuing a roundabout way of accomplishing this, but I had a list called "`goodAttributes`" and a dataframe called `QTable`. If a column name of `QTable` is in "`goodAttributes`" than I want to return the max of that column, otherwise I want to return the minimum of the column...

I checked if the column name of `QTable` was in the list "`goodAttributes`" using "`grepl`" and then reset the column names of `QTable` if the value was in the list "`goodAttributes`" as "True" and otherwise set the column name as "`False`", and called the new table `QTable2`.

**Current DataFrame called "QTableB":**

[image]

Now, if the column name of `QTableB` is "`True`" I want to find the maximum of that column, and if the column name of `QTableB` is "`False`" I want to return the minimum of that column... storing the results in a new data frame.

Comment: Edit your question. (Don't use comments.) Post data as text and then show your code. Not my downvote. (Somebody else saw the same problems and was lazy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to simply apply a function to all of the `colnames` of the frame:

```
QTable  <- data.frame(v1=1:10,v2=11:20,v3=31:40)
goodAttributes <- c("v1","v3")

sapply(colnames(QTable),function(c){
  if(c %in% goodAttributes) max(QTable[,c])
  else min(QTable[,c])})
```

which yields

```
v1 v2 v3 
10 11 40
```

i.e. the max of v1 and v3 (the column names in `goodAttributes`) and the min of v2.